# Como poner por defecto true en un checkbox que esta en una tabla? java

Tags: java, checkbox

Holas gente, tengo una tabla en netbeans donde una de las columnas tiene un valor boolean, es decir que me lo convierte en un checkbox, mi tema, es que quiero que por defecto los checkbox esten marcados... y no encuentro como

Comment: Agrega tu código para ser más específicos en las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando swing usa el método[`setSelected()`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JCheckBoxsetSelectedbooleanb.htm)

```
myCheckBox.setSelected(true);
```